# How to set value in Lookup fields

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set Lookup field via JQuery.

[image: Input field without id and value can not be found]

Comment: you want to locate filed , right ?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle demo.

Comment: You say Lookup fields, Is this SharePoint related?

Comment: It's related to UMT 360 implemented inside Project & SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use val() method

```
$( ".umt-fieldtable-selectedItems" ).val("value");
```

To get value

```
var value = $('.umt-fieldtable-selectedItems').val();
```

According to [this](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

you can locate filed by its [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) using jquery

```
let field = $('.umt-fieldtable-selectedItems');
fiel.val('value');
```

Comment: @ParthSRawal - can you able to provide code at jsfiddle

Comment: The only reason I could see this not working is if the element doesn't exist when it's called. Are you running this logic within a document.ready handler? Is the element you're trying to target dynamically created?

Comment: I believe It's SharePoint related, the id and classes of the elements looks very much like sharepoint, and if it is then he has to do it another way to populate a lookup field with jquery